# Truncate does not run in SSIS batch process

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have an Execute SQL Task which does a very simple Truncate Table. I have declared table name as variable and in the Expressions, I have set SqlStatementSource as "Truncate Table " + @[User::TableName]

I have also declared the variable in Parameter Mapping

[image]

[image]

The execute task runs the package successfully. But the same, when I execute via the batch file, I get this error:

> Description: Executing the query "" failed with the following error:
> "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {32E37890-EC10-4F89-8D74-1B8CAA4C95F2} failed due to the following
> error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x800700C1).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the
> query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set
> correctly, or connection not established correctly.

What is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing your options.

For Parameters, it is driver dependent. OLE/ODBC use an ordinal based placeholder `?` while ADO uses a named parameter `@param1` format

However, you're not going to be able to use `TRUNCATE TABLE ?` with parameterization (or any query that attempts to sub out the table name).

Instead, what you're looking for is an Expression. Expressions can exist on any thing in SSIS. Nearly every Task exposes them, and they even exist on SSIS Variables.

What I would do,

### Step 1

Create a second variable, `@[User::QueryTruncate]` of type String. In the Expression column (after Value), use the following

```
"TRUNCATE TABLE " + @[User::TableName]
```

Click evaluate and confirm it renders

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[ng]
```

Now you have an expression that changes whenever the value of TableName changes.

### Step 2

Configure the Execute SQL Task to have a `SQLSourceType` of `Variable`
In the `SourceVariable` choose @[User::QueryTruncate]

Clear any mappings you may have in the parameter mapping tab.

### But there are Expressions on the Execute SQL Task

Yes, there is an option for building the expression we use to create QueryTruncate, so why not just do it in the task? It will save us a variable and we know, doing less makes things go faster!

True. Absolutely true. However, when an expression goes "wrong" it is impossible to debug what it is. What command did we send to the database? You can't inspect the SSIS package to find out. But, if you've put an Expression on a Variable, it's trivial to set a breakpoint on the offending and inspect the value immediately before the Task executes.

Build out a series of expressions that exist in all of your packages i.e. QueryTruncate, QuerySource, QueryUpdate and now you are on the road to consistent, reusable package patterns.

### Addressing defects in SQL Server 2019

While I'm happy to entertain the possibility of there being a bug in the product: a package with an Execute Task, driven by a Variable, which has has an expression building out a TRUNCATE TABLE statement works just fine from the command line

[image]

Comment: Great, your solution works perfect when I run as a SSIS package from Visual Studio, but, I get below error when I run as a batch file:

Description: Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {32E37890-EC10-4F89-8D74-1B8CAA4C95F2} failed due to the following error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Warning: 2022-08-16 18:51:22.94
   Code: 0x80019002
   Source: Package
   Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
End Warning
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). @billinkc

Comment: What are the commands in the batch file? On what machine is the batch file being executed? If the batch file is on your desktop and you've not installed the developer edition of SQL Server, that error message is going to be a licensing error indicating you can't run SSIS outside of the context of Visual Studio environment. The next most probable error is a mismatch between the dtexec.exe and the target version of the .dtsx/.ispac file

Comment: Actually the problem is with the SSIS and Visual Studio. It seems to be a Microsoft Bug.

Solution - I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019 and installed Visual Studio 2015 and SSDT 2015 17.4.

The package is now successful, executing from the batch file / executing as a task from Visual Studio. Many thanks for your prompt support. God Bless!

Answer (score 0):

@billinkc - Actually the problem is with the SSIS and Visual Studio. It seems to be a Microsoft Bug.

Solution - I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019 and installed Visual Studio 2015 and SSDT 2015 17.4.

The package is now successful, executing from the batch file / executing as a task from Visual Studio.